Simplest way to create Lettuce beans in Spring?
I want to invoke Redis's FUNCTION LOAD and FCALL commands, but there are no corresponding methods in the classes under org.springframework.data.redis package (if there are, please tell me). So I have to use Lettuce directly in Spring.
I found how to use Lettuce in this post:
@Configuration
class RedisConfiguration  {
    @Value("${spring.redis.host}")
    private String redisHost;

    @Value("${spring.redis.port}")
    private int redisPort;

    @Bean
    public RedisClient redisClient() {
        var redisURI = RedisURI.create(redisHost, redisPort);
        return RedisClient.create(redisURI);
    }

    @Bean
    public StatefulRedisConnection<String, String> redisConnection(
        RedisClient client
    ) {
        return client.connect();
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisCommands redisCommands(
        StatefulRedisConnection<String, String> connection
    ) {
        return connection.sync();
    }
}

It looks simple, but will get complex if sentinel and other configuration properties are considerated. Hence Spring already configured Lettuce in spring-data-redis, I want to use and create Lettuce objects from existing beans like this:
@Bean
public StatefulRedisConnection<String, String> redisConnection(
    LettuceConnectionFactory factory  // this bean exists in spring-data-redis
) {
    var client = factory.getRequiredNativeClient();
    if (!(client instanceof RedisClient)) {
        // The type declaration of `client` is `AbstractRedisClient`.
        // The actual class is `RedisClient` in most cases but not always.
        throw new RuntimeException("Unsupported Redis configuration");
    }
    return ((RedisClient)client).connect();
}

It works, but looks not ideal. Is there a better way to create Lettuce beans?
